# EF Core 8 requires default DbContext constructor when managing migrations so can't access Configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, .net-core

I upgraded my .NET and EF project from 5 to 8 and immediately had issues with managing migrations (I use the Package Manager Console).

Previously, I had the following DbContext class:

```
public class PortalDbContext : DbContext {

    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public PortalDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<PortalDbContext> options,
        IConfiguration config) : base(options) {

        _config = config;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        //... assorted entity defs

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("PortalDBConnection"));
        }
    }   
}
```

After upgrading to 8, I had to add a default no parameter constructor for EF to be able to manage migrations (add, update, etc.), otherwise it would throw an unable to resolve service error.

```
public PortalDbContext() {}
```

But because it isn't using the custom constructor with the config parameter, I can't use GetConnection String in the OnConfiguring call.

I got past it by entering the connection string directly in the UseSqlServer call

```
if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) {
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=xxxxx, etc.");
}
```

But I really want to be able to have the config string defined solely in the appsettings.json file as I regularly swap to different databases for dev and testing.

Is there a way to make Configuration accessible to EF when managing migrations?

Note that I am using the Package Manager Console to as the CLI and have the default project set to the project that contains the DbContext class.

Also, I have the following in startup but that doesn't get used when managing migrations in the PMC console:

```
services.AddDbContext<PortalDbContext>(options =>                
     options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("PortalDBConnection")));
```

Comment: I'm guessing the service that can't be resolved is `IConfiguration`. I think you should decouple your DB context from this type. Note that you can pass the connection string from the command line when running migrations or another, but obviously you can access the configuration file by deserializing it.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, right after I post the question, I find the answer (thanks Chat GPT). Need to setup a configuration pointing to appsettings.json in the OnConfiguring call:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {

        if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured) {

            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("PortalDBConnection"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: See also: [from-application-services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-application-services)

Comment: Yes, I was just reading that. From what I can tell, the tool should be able to get to startup.cs to get the configuration but it isn't. It is possible that because my project was updated from 5 to 8, as opposed to created from scratch, I don't have the right hooks.

Comment: See [Common Options: `--startup-project`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#common-options). But comparing to a freshly scaffolded dotnet 8 project is a good idea that you hint at.

Comment: That startup option is for using the EF CLI. I'm using the Package Manager Console (as recommended by that article) and I have set the startup project in the PMC via its UI. I'll try to compare to a new project when I get some breathing room.

Comment: @Alex Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people